# What is the equivalent function that generate a "-L" and -rpath flag in g++

Tags: c++, cmake, makefile

When I compile my c++ program using manually written makefile, I use the following command:

```
LNK_FLAG      = -L $(LIB_PATH) -lnameofmylib
RPATH_FLAG    = -Wl,-rpath,$(LIB_PATH)
```

and I use `make LIB_PATH=/path/to/my/lib` to build my program.

Now I want to use cmake to build my program, so, I wonder if there are some mechanisms to do that? or do I have to use `set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -L ${LIB_PATH} -lnameofmylib -Wl,-rpath,${LIB_PATH}")`?

Comment: Too many questions in one post: `-L` and `-l` options are described in @Joel answer, setting `LIB_PATH` for use in makefile may be replaced with `set(LIB_PATH <...> CACHE ...)` in CMake, RPATH handling in CMake is described in [Wiki](https://cmake.org/Wiki/CMake_RPATH_handling).

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=cmake+rpath and https://www.google.com/search?q=cmake+linking+library

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CMake link to external library](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8774593/cmake-link-to-external-library)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to add a library search path, use [link_directories](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/link_directories.html). For linking a library, use [link_libraries](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/link_libraries.html). This can be  portable on any OS or compiler/linker, or less your are using compiler dependend features.